# What does the 5th column mean in the lsscsi output?

Tags: linux, disk

List SCSI devices in my os:

```
debian@debian:~$ lsscsi
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST500DM002-1BD14 KC66  /dev/sda 
[1:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD2500AAKX-0 1H15  /dev/sdb 
[4:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST1000VX000      SC23  /dev/sdc 
[9:0:0:0]    disk    Innostor Innostor         1.00  /dev/sdd
```

What does the 5th column mean in the lsscsi output?

```
debian@debian:~$ lsscsi  | awk '{print $5}'
KC66
WD2500AAKX-0
SC23
1.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns are:

- [scsi_host:channel:target_number:LUN]
- SCSI peripheral type
- vendor name
- model name
- revision string

So the fifth column is the revision string. You can also use `lsscsi -c` to print in the classic mode, where these are printed in a different form and prefixed:

```
$ lsscsi
[9:0:5:0]    disk    QEMU     QEMU HARDDISK    2.5+  /dev/sda

$ lscscsi -c
Host: scsi9 Channel: 00 Target: 05 Lun: 00
  Vendor: QEMU     Model: QEMU HARDDISK    Rev: 2.5+
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
```

Btw. in your case `WDC WD2500AAKX-0` actually appears to be the model name with a space and `1H15` is the revision.

You can read more about lsscsi [here](https://sg.danny.cz/scsi/lsscsi.html).